# (PHP) Grabbing AccessToken and feed without permission. (sorta)

Tags: php, facebook, feed, status, access-token

I'm beginning a blog and I wanted to make a 'FacebookStatusApp' for the blog.
All it has to do is get my latest status and get request it to my translator page.
I can get my latest feed but the problem is the accesstoken.
I found a way to keep refreshing my access_token every 9 minutes. It's a site called:

https://mywebcron.com/

This site will call your url every X minutes. I chose 9 minutes.

My renew code is pretty simple:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("fbat.txt");
$token = $file;

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=100000280644272&client_secret=secret&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=".$token;

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
$err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);

$paramsfb = null;
//parse_str($contents, $paramsfb);
echo $contents;
?>
```

"Fbat.txt" contains the current AccessToken.

But I need a client_secret for my account.
And I can't get a AccessToken for my facebook account :/

So my solution was creating a new app using MY ClientID and HIS ClientSecret with the 'GRAPH EXPLORER' to generate a access_token.

So my question is:
How can I get MY latest status AND MY access_token. ?

If there is a good alternative (Ex. Using an APP) I could do that too.

Well, I hope you understand my question :P

Comment: Ah, I changed the app to use in graphExplorer and then generated a key. This works! And the regenerating works. But will the accesstoken get lost when I logout?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your feed needs to be public.  The below code should do the rest:

```
function fb_setup(){

    $app_id = 'APP_ID';
    $app_secret = 'APP_SECRET';

    $response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id='.$app_id.'&client_secret='.$app_secret);

    $token = str_replace('access_token=', '', $response);

    $node = "PAGE_ID(if not a page just use 'me')";
    $fields = array();
    $fields[] = 'feed';
    $fields[] = 'likes';

    $response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$node.'?fields='.implode(',', $fields).'&access_token='.$token.'');

    $arr = json_decode($response);

    $data['node'] = $node;
    $data['arr'] = $arr;

    return $data;

}
function last_post(){

    $ret = fb_setup();
    $arr = $ret['arr'];
    $node = $ret['node'];

    $feed = $arr->feed->data;

    $ret = "";
    $ret .= "<div id='last-fb-post'>";
    $item = $feed[0];

    $message = str_replace("\n","</p><p>",$item->message);
    $likes = (!$item->likes->count) ? '0' : $item->likes->count;
    $coms = $item->comments->count;
    $ex_id = explode('_',$item->id);
    $id = $ex_id[1];

    $href = 'http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid='.$id.'&id='.$node;

    $ret .= '<a class="title" target="_blank" href="'.$href.'">Last Update: <u>' . date("F j, Y",strtotime($item->created_time)) . '</u></a>';
    if($item->type == 'photo'){
        $ret .= '<div class="fb_img"><a target="_blank" href="'.$href.'"><img src="'.$item->picture.'"/></a></div>';
    }
    $ret .= "<p class=\"msg\">";
    $ret .= $message;
    $ret .= "</p>";
    $ret .= "<p class='likes'><a htarget=\"_blank\" href=\"$href\">$likes</p>";



    $ret .= "</div>";

    return $ret;

}
```

Comment: I understand what you did. But you cant use: file_get_contents on a httpS:// link. So I'll be using curl. Thanks!

Comment: Ok unos problemos. I might've said it wrong but I need 'Status' field which doesn't go that easy :/ I've managed to make a working one but for some reason it doesnt update. How can I send you the source code? BTW: it only doesnt update on the webhost. It does on my local machine

Comment: Could it be a catching issue?  And you can use file_get_contents with https link, try `ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);` before you call the function.